# Adding activity indicator to a custom button not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i need to add activity indicators above the buttons whenever it has been clicked.I made all the custom buttons like this and add it to navigation bar.`

```
UIButton *btnNext1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnNext1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100,38, 38);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]; 
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,5,38,38); 
[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];// position it to the middle 
[btnNext1 setBackgroundImage:imageView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
[imageView release]; 
[btnNext1 addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btnNext =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnNext1];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnNext;
[btnNext release];
```

then in the sender methode i tried

```
UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

// Position the spinner
[myIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(button.frame.size.width / 2,button.frame.size.height /2)];

// Add to button
[button addSubview:myIndicator];

// Start the animation
[myIndicator startAnimating];
```

But it is not showing up. Can anybody point me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are adding your indicator to a button?

Comment: yes...exactly thats wat i need

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: what is 'button.' in your Add to button section

Comment: @manujmv there is no . its by mistake.pls check the edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this in button action

```
UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]                                           initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[myIndicator setCenter:button.center];
[button addSubview:myIndicator];
[button bringSubviewToFront:myIndicator];
[myIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your code  it working fine may be the image and indicator both are same color or you are calling different method ,otherwise it's working fine.
once check below images.

before and after button actions
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your sender method to

```
UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                            initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

// Position the spinner
[myIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(button.frame.size.width / 2,button.frame.size.height /2)];

// Add to button
[self addSubview:myIndicator];

// Start the animation
[myIndicator startAnimating];
```

**You need to add indicator to uiview rather than button.**